# Expected 'var' to have a typedef

Tags: typescript

I'm thinking about using [TSLint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) to do static analysis of my code before shipping. However I got a lot of errors that I'm thinking are not accurate.

For example, If I analyze this line of code:

```
let hello = "Hello!";
```

Which I get from [TypeScript](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/variable-declarations.html) official web site, I got this error in TSLint:

> Expected 'hello' to have a typedef

To avoid this error, I have to change my code like:

```
let hello:string = "Hello!";
```

It seems ugly and redundant to keep specifying types.

Should I ignore these type of errors or use second code?

Comment: Whether you should or not is entirely up to you.

Comment: If you want to use a lint program you should consider everything it could warn you about and decide which set of warnings you need for your particular coding conventions. In no cases should you take a lint program and simply assume every warning is something you care about.

Comment: The idea of TypeScript is - you guessted it - using types. If you don't want to use types, you can disable [`typedef`](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/typedef/) tslint rule or use plain js instead. I would suggest specifying types everywhere, though.

Comment: @kamyl in typescript when you do `let hello = "Hello!"` the variable `hello` is typed as a `string`, you don't have to tell the compiler explicitly in simple cases like that. The point is though that some people might feel as you perhaps do that specifiying all of the types explicitly is clearer, so TSLint allows you to enforce that programming style. Others of us feel that more concise coding is a good thing so we leave types out when they are correctly inferred, so if I used TSLint I would disable that warning. Neither of us is wrong, it's purely down to style.

Comment: I typically allow implicit types, but wherever I do specify types, I *always* use a pattern where I put spaces around the colon, like this `let hello : string = "Hello!;"` or `(first : string, last : string) => {...}`. I think it's looks **much** neater and better differentiates type specifications from object assignments.

Comment: @ABabin I recommend only having formatting preferences that can automated by your tools and shared by all contributors.

Comment: @Fenton Is there any reason that can't be done with the format I mentioned?

Comment: @ABabin - only you can decide, by talking to the other contributors to your code base.

Comment: @Fenton Ah, well I know that. I thought you were telling me my pattern couldn't be automated or shared with other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

When TSLint or other tools say something stupid, it is important that we (as smart humans) tell it otherwise.

There are some cases where you might want to prompt for an explicit type annotation (perhaps more with functions), but variables are not such a place.

Ideally, you should get [TSLint to prompt you to remove easily inferred types](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-inferrable-types/).